# Access 2010 Database Clenup

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have problems with my records within my database, so I have a template with about 260,000 records and for each record they have 3 identification columns to determine what time period the record is from and location: one for year, one for month, and one for region. Then the information for identifying the specific item is TagName, and Description. The Problem I am having is when someone entered data into this database they entered different description for the same device, I know this because the tag name is the same. Can I write code that will go through the data base find the items with the same tag name and use one of the descriptions to replace the ones that are different to have a more uniform database. Also some devices do not have tag names so we would want to avoid the "" Case.

Also moving forward into the future I have added more columns to the database to allow for more information to be retrieved, is there a way that I can back fill the data to older records once I know that they have the same tag name and Description once the database is cleaned up? Thanks in advance for the information it is much appreciated.

I assume that this will have to be done with VBA of some sort to modify records by looking for the first record with that description and using a variable to assign that description to all the other items with the same tag name? I just am not sure of the correct VBA syntax to go about this. I assume a similar method would be used for the backfilling process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is rather broad and multifaceted, so I'll answer key parts in steps:

> The Problem I am having is when someone entered data into this
>   database they entered different description for the same device, I
>   know this because the tag name is the same.

While you could fix up those inconsistencies easily enough with a bit of SQL code, it would be better to avoid those inconsistencies being possible in the first place:

1. Create a new table, let's call it 'Tags', with TagName and TagDescription fields, and with TagName set as the primary key. Ensure both fields have their Required setting to True and Allow Zero Length to False.
2. Populate this new table with all possible tags - you can do this with a one-off 'append query' in Access jargon (INSERT INTO statement in SQL).
3. Delete the tag description column from the main table.
4. Go into the Relationships view and add a one-to-many relation between the two tables, linking the TagName field in the main table to the TagName field in the Tags table.
5. As required, create a query that aggregates data from the two tables.

> Also some devices do not have tag names so we would want to avoid the
>   "" Case.

In Access, the concept of an empty string ("") is different from the concept of a true blank or 'null'. As such, it would be a good idea to replace all empty strings (if there are any) with nulls -

```
UPDATE MyTable SET TagName = Null WHERE TagName = '';
```

You can then set the TagName field's Allow Zero Length property to False in the table designer.

> Also moving forward into the future I have added more columns to the
>   database to allow for more information to be retrieved

Think less in terms of more columns than more tables.

> I assume that this will have to be done with VBA of some sort to modify records

Either VBA, SQL, or the Access query designers (which create SQL code behind the scenes). In terms of being able to crunch through data the quickest, SQL is best, though pure VBA (and in particular, using the DAO object library) can be easier to understand and follow.

Comment: Thanks for the information as for data entry problems, this database was a old one handed to me so I am fixing up inconsistencies that I have found to eliminate these problems because I know all about: Data Validation, and Referential Integrity.

Comment: @ColdTeck - I'd suggest splitting out what you originally posted into discrete questions then. That said, I still think fixing the data structure will probably be the best way to clean up the data.